# Why we must do defensive copying for imutable classes

Tags: java, immutability, copying

why we must do Defensive Copying in order to achieve Immutable class?
Look at this code:

```
public final class EmailMessage   {
    private final String from;
    private final String to;
    private final String message;
    private final Date   date;

    public EmailMessage( String from, String to, String msg, Date date )
    {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
        this.message = msg;
        this.date = new Date(date.getTime());// instead of date;
    }

    public String getFrom()
    {
        return( from );
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return( new Date( date.getTime() ); // instead of Date
    }
}
```

Why it won't be Immutable if we didn't do Defensive Copying?

Comment: because `Date` class is mutable, even if you declare its instance final, value still can be altered by `setDay()` and other setters. Copying `date` from constructor argument you cannot guarantee that references won't be kept in outer code thus making it possible to change.

Comment: This bad design problem is solved in `java.util.time` package in Java 8, where you should use `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and other classes that are all fully immutable and safe.

Comment: you can use jodatime to remove design issues or java.util.time (from Java 8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to achieve immutability you must make copies of all mutable objects passed into your constructor, and also return copies for all mutable objects stored inside your class, if any.

- If you do not make a copy of the date passed into you, the caller can change the date after your object has been constructed, effectively mutating it.
- If you do not return a copy from a getter of a mutable object, the callers can mutate the object that they get from you, effectively mutating your object as well.

In your specific example, `Date` class is mutable. If yo skip copying in the constructor, malicious code can do this:

```
Date d = new ...
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage("lazy dog", "quick brown fox", "Jump!", d);
d.setTime(d.getTime()+12345); // Changes the date inside msg
```

If you skip the second copy, the callers can do this:

```
EmailMessage msg = ...
Date d = msg.getDate();
d.setTime(d.getTime()+12345); // Changes the date inside msg
```

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise it is possible to change the object state. Let's imagine, that your `getDate` method is the following:

```
public Date getDate() {
    return date; // instead of Date
}
```

And we use it in the following way:

```
EmailMessage msg = new EmailMessage(...); // initialization
Date date = msg.getDate();
date.setTime(...); //ooops, our msg object has another date now
```